# How to create kafka-node js API to call it from react native application

Tags: node.js, react-native, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

In my project, I want use kafka in node js and want to create its API sothat I can call kafka(producer functionality) from react native application.
(Actual use case: I want to send a meeting ID from react native app to some end user via kafka topic)

In short, I want to call kafka producer from my react native app keeping nodejs as my server.

AFAIK, we can not integrate kafka directly with react native app.

Need your expert advice on how can we achieve this functionality.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to call kafka producer from my react native app keeping nodejs as my server. What should be the flow ? Thanks